# scraping name of dataset in kaggle using python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, kaggle

***Hi,
Please how can i get the name of dataset in kaggle, usign beatiful soup or selenium or scrapy.
I test this code but no return :***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/heptapod/titanic'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
datasetName = soup.find('h5',{'class':'sc-dIvrsQ sc-hHEiqL sc-kaPsuu kSVYRu ccTnQh ffXPrd'})

print(datasetName)
```

***see the picture :***
[inspect element from kaggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm5w1.png)

Comment: That class name has a lot of randomization. Most probably, it is dynamic in nature, i.e., it would not be the same for every instance. Why don't you use Selenium to get the name?
I used the selenium approach and got it, but I don't see `titanic.csv`, instead I found `train and test2csv`. Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'yourdriverpath', options=opt)

driver.get("https://www.kaggle.com/heptapod/titanic")
time.sleep(5)
datasetname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button']//div//div").text
print(datasetname)
```

Output:

```
train_and_test2.csv

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKRSl.png)

Comment: Thank  you,  and i don't want my chrome to open, how can i remove that ?

Comment: You have to use `headless chrome`. Updated the answer. please check. And if the answer works out, please accept. Thanks!